# Firefox: "clicking" on the contents of an xhr response

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest

So for various reasons, I have to send a xmlhttprequest and click on a button in the response. My code looks like this:

```
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var param_result = document.createElement("div");
    param_result.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    param_result.getElementsByClassName("submit")[0].click();
}
```

For some reason, this works in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem; it seems as if dumping the results of a xhr into a div is not sufficient for firefox to load the document.

After physically making a hidden div and setting the response as the inner html, I was able to click on the button.

(Whether this is good programming behaviour is questionable, but it got me around the current problem until I talked to the sysadmin about changing the server-side code)